How can I find all exact occurrences of a string, or close matches of it, in a longer string in Python?
Goal:

I'd like to find all exact occurrences of a string, or close matches of it, in a longer string in Python.
I'd also like to know the location of these occurrences in the longer string.
To define what a close match is, I'd like to set a threshold, e.g. number of edits if using the edit distance as the metric.
I'd also like the code to give a matching score (the one that is likely used to determine if a candidate substring is over the matching threshold I set).

How can I do so in Python?

Example:
long_string = """1. Bob likes classical music very much.
2. This is classic music!
3. This is a classic musical. It has a lot of classical musics.
"""

query_string = "classical music"

I'd like the Python code to find "classical music" and possibly "classic music", "classic musical" and "classical musics" depending on the string matching threshold I set.

Research: I found Checking fuzzy/approximate substring existing in a longer string, in Python? but the question focuses on the best match only (i.e., not all occurrences) and answers either also focuses on the best match or don't work on multi-word query strings  (since the question only had a single-word query strings, or return some incorrect score (doesn't get a perfect score even for an exact match).

I wouldn't think that a "classic musical" would be strongly correlated to "classical music" but presumably that's just an example.

@jarmod yes, just an example

nltk lib might can help

The regex solution in the other question would trivially do what you ask.

@tripleee thanks, which one? there are 3 different answers using regex

@tripleee added an answer showing shortcomings.

rapidfuzz is very fast and can use a threshold. See rapidfuzz.fuzz.ratio

@user19077881 thanks good to know! Does rapidfuzz have a find_near_matches feature as fuzzysearch does?

The accepted answer shows how to implement fuzzy searching with the regex library using its {e=42} extension for specifying edit distance. A regex search will easily allow you to access all available matches (regex.finditer() and friends). Though now that you edited in an additional requirement to rank the matches, it no longer does everything you ask for.

Reddit user throwaway6560192 pointed me to a good solution: use fuzzysearch.find_near_matches().
import pprint
from fuzzysearch import find_near_matches

long_string = """1. Bob likes classical music very much.
2. This is classic music!
3. This is a classic musical. It has a lot of classical musics.
"""

query_string = "classical music"
pprint.pprint(find_near_matches(query_string, long_string, max_l_dist=5))

outputs:
[Match(start=13, end=28, dist=0, matched='classical music'),
 Match(start=51, end=64, dist=2, matched='classic music'),
 Match(start=79, end=92, dist=2, matched='classic music'),
 Match(start=112, end=127, dist=0, matched='classical music')]


And here's is my weak solution with the regex lib so far:
import regex
long_string = """1. Bob likes classical music very much.
2. This is classic music!
3. This is a classic musical. It has a lot of classical musics.
"""

query_string = "classical music"
threshold = 5

results = regex.finditer(r'(classical music){e<5}', long_string, flags=regex.IGNORECASE)

for result in results:
    print(result)

Output:
<regex.Match object; span=(9, 28), match='kes classical music', fuzzy_counts=(0, 4, 0)>
<regex.Match object; span=(49, 64), match='s classic music', fuzzy_counts=(0, 2, 2)>
<regex.Match object; span=(77, 92), match='a classic music', fuzzy_counts=(0, 2, 2)>
<regex.Match object; span=(108, 127), match=' of classical music', fuzzy_counts=(0, 4, 0)>

2 weaknesses of that  solution with the regex lib:

Doesn't use query_string and threshold but instead hardcode them in the regex query.
Doesn't get best matches but instead get matches with 4 errors.


You can easily parametrize the regex search by using something like f"{query_string}{{e<{threshold}}}" for the regex to search for. I thought you were specifically asking to get all matches; now you are complaining that it does that?

If you dislike the bleed into surrounding contexts, you can easily write a more demanding regex which requires the match to be confined by word boundaries; like \b(classical music){e<4}\b

Here is a simple class that uses the regex package. You provide a query with one or more space separated terms in the format: "term{limit}" (exs: "home{5}", "class{4} music{4}").

limits {x}:

indicate that 0 to limit non-whitespace characters may appear where the limit is placed
can be placed anywhere in the term (ex: "{1}ward{4}")
can be indicated with "~" instead of {x} (ex: "~ward~~~~")


import regex
from   typing import Iterator

# alias long-winded types
Iter  = list|tuple|set
Flags = None|regex.RegexFlag
Match = regex.Match

__all__ = ('FuzzBiz', )

"""
https://github.com/mrabarnett/mrab-regex?tab=readme-ov-file#approximate-fuzzy-matching-hg-issue-12-hg-issue-41-hg-issue-109
"""
class FuzzBiz:
    CHAR = '~' # substitution and deletion character
        
    # `.sub` replacement method    
    @staticmethod
    def _repl(match:Match) -> str:
        return FuzzBiz.CHAR * int(match.group(1))
            
    # format the query for fuzzy matching        
    @staticmethod
    def _term(query:str) -> str:
        # where x is an integer, sub "{x}" with x amount of CHAR characters
        term  = regex.sub(r'\{(\d+)\}', FuzzBiz._repl, query)
        limit = term.count(FuzzBiz.CHAR) # determine limit
        
        # return formatted term
        return f'({term}){{{limit+1}i+1d+1s<={limit}:\S}}'
    
    """ find all instances that match a singular search
        `text` : the text to be searched
        `query`: the term to search for
        `skip` : Iter of words and/or characters that trigger a skip when found in a result - DEFAULT: []
        `flags`: regex flags to apply to this expression                                    - DEFAULT: regex.VERSION1
    """        
    @staticmethod
    def finditer(text:str, query:str, skip:None|Iter=None, flags:Flags=None) -> Iterator:
        # default optional arguments
        flags = flags or regex.VERSION1
        skip  = skip  or []
        
        # process all query terms and format to pattern
        expr = r'\s'.join(map(FuzzBiz._term, query.split(' ')))
        expr = fr'\m(?P<result>{expr})\M'
        
        for m in regex.finditer(expr, text, flags=flags):
            result = m['result']
            
            # determine if result should be skipped
            for item in skip:
                if item in result: break
            else:
                yield m.span(), result
     
    """ make multiple consecutive searches
        `text`           : the text to be searched
        `queries`        : Iter of search terms
        `*args|**kwargs` : passed to `.finditer` as remaining args
    """    
    @staticmethod
    def iterall(text:str, queries:Iter, *args, **kwargs) -> Iterator:
        # query is managed internally
        if kwargs.get('query'): del kwargs['query']
        
        for query in queries:
            q = query
                
            for span, match in FuzzBiz.finditer(text, query, *args, **kwargs):
                yield q, span, match
                q = None # only yield `query` the first time it is encountered

            


.iterall test
data = """ 
I headed homeward to meet with the Wardens. 
When I arrived, I was greeted by a homely man that told me the homestead was awarded 5 million dollars.
We intend to use some of the homage to create a homeless ward. 
The first piece of furniture will be my late-friend Homer's wardrobe.
"""
queries = 'home{5}', '~ward~~~', 'home{4} ward{4}', 'th~~', '{2}e'

for term, span, match in FuzzBiz.iterall(data, queries, flags=regex.I):
    if term: print(f'\n{term.upper()}')
    print(f'  {match}') 

output
HOME{5}
  homeward
  homely
  homestead
  homeless
  Homer's

~WARD~~~
  Wardens
  awarded
  ward

HOME{4} WARD{4}
  homeless ward
  Homer's wardrobe

TH~~
  the
  that
  the
  the
  The

{2}E
  the
  me
  the
  We
  use
  the
  The
  be


.finditer test
data = """ 
I would classify music as one of my favorite hobbies. 
I love classical music played by classy musicians for a classic musical. 
Beethoven can not be out-classed, music-wise - a man of class, musically gifted.
"""
query = 'class{4} music{5}'

print(f'\n{query.upper()}')
for span, match in FuzzBiz.finditer(data, query, skip=('classify', ',')):  
    print(f'  {match}')

output
CLASS{4} MUSIC{5}
  classical music
  classy musicians
  classic musical


Maybe also point out the regex.ENHANCEMATCH flag which sometimes improves on the results you would otherwise get out of the box.

@tripleee - I'm not sure how to implement that here or if it's even necessary, because this already works very well. I wrote over 100 "tricky" tests and it didn't fail a single one.

My proposed fix to the OP's "classical music" answer would not work properly without it.

@tripleee - This solution does not need that. Please try to trick my code based on the "rules" I described in the beginning of the post. I haven't been able to, and I tried 100 times multiplied by the search instances in each attempt.
